# Error in MKCoordinateSpan, says to run before the self is available

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, core-location

I was integrating my app with a map, and when I declare a variable span with `MKCoordinateSpan` type, it gives me this error:

> Cannot use instance member 'latDelta' within property initializer;
>   property initializers run before 'self' is available

Also when I write other types such as: `CLLocationCoordinate2D` or `MKCoordinateRegion` it still says me that the variable within the property initializer cannot be used.

I don't know what the problem is, any help would be appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!

    let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = 42.8
    let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = 74.6
    let latDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05
    let lonDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05

    let span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: latDelta, longitudeDelta: lonDelta)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That is not correct way to initialise values. but you can do that in any other class method. Check below code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!

    let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = 42.8
    let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = 74.6
    let latDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05
    let lonDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05

    //Declare it here
    var span: MKCoordinateSpan?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Assign values here in method
        span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: latDelta, longitudeDelta: lonDelta)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize following in `viewDidLoad()`

```
let span: MKCoordinateSpan?;
```

And in `viewDidLoad()`

```
span  = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: latDelta, longitudeDelta: lonDelta);
```